# Store number from user EditText in variable Java Android

Tags: java, android, variables, android-edittext

How to store a number from edittext in a variable (integer) each time when user enter a number and to use the variable in 'onSensorChanged'? Like here: if (event.values[0] == (1 - UserInputVariable))  {acceleration.setText(UserInputVariable);}

My code is:

```
Sensor accelerometer;
SensorManager sm;
TextView acceleration;

  EditText mEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    acceleration=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.acceleration);


        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);




}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

     if (event.values[0] == 1)  {
            acceleration.setText(mEdit);

        }

     else{  acceleration.setText("X: "+event.values[0]+
            "\nY:"+event.values[1]);
     }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        doSomething();

    } 

});
```

you can use edit text change listener to handle whenever user enter something.

Comment: And I can add mEdit to if (event.values[0] == (1 - mEdit )) {acceleration.setText('something');} ?

Comment: you'll get value from the edittext, s is the new value and you can convert it to int or use it as it is. Put it in another global value and use it.